# Use Underscore.js to retrieve top n elements from array ranked by some property

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array of objects in javascript. Each object is of the form

```
obj {
    location: "left", // some string
    weight: 1.25 // some real, positive number
}
```

Let us assume the length of the array is greater than 500.

I want to return a filtered copy of the array where only the top 500 elements as ranked by the `weight` property are present. In other words, I want the array with objects with the 500 highest `weight`s

What is the clean way to do this with underscore?

Comment: A simple sort-and-slice will do, but there is no efficient top-k implementation in underscore.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it with normal javascript, put this in a function and it should work. Just pass in the array you want to sort as `myArray`. Sorry for lack of explanation, on my phone.

```
var sorted = myArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.weight - b.weight; // sort by weight, low to heigh
}).reverse(); // then reverse to get high to low

return sorted.slice(0, 500); // slice the first 500
```

Comment: Nice answer, but question was regarding `underscore`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `sortBy()` to sort the array in descending order by weight and use `first()` to take the first 500...

```
var top500 = _.chain(myObjects)
              .sortBy(function(item) { return item.weight * -1; })
              .first(500)
              .value();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sortedArr = arr.sort(function(l, r) { return r.weight - l.weight; }).slice(0, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you care about efficiency (e.g., for a large array), use the quickselect algorithm to find top-k in O(n) and then sort the k in O(klogk). Or even performing heapsort with a fixed heap size would be O(nlogk) (for example, use a library like [heap.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/heap) to accomplish this using its `nlargest` or `nsmallest` method). In comparison, sorting the entire array first and the using `slice` would be O(nlogn).